# Seekbar is crashing app

Tags: android

Whenever I

```
    seekBar.setMax(20);
    seekBar.setProgress(10);
```

the app crashes. One or both of these crashes the app. (Are they deprecated?)
If I comment these two lines out and add the
setOnSeekBarChangeListener, then the listener will crash the app.

I'm not sure why, but I'm having issues using the Seekbar. Any help is super appreciated.

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.test.timestableapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView timesTableListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SeekBar timesTablesSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // timesTablesSeekBar.setMax(20);
       // timesTablesSeekBar.setProgress(10);
                timesTablesSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                        int min = 1;
                        int timesTableNumber;
                        if (i < min)
                        {
                            timesTableNumber = min;
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                timesTableNumber = i;
                            }
                            Log.i("Seekbar Value", Integer.toString(timesTableNumber));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you inflating the layout?

Comment: Yes, @SrikarReddy is right. You forgot `setContentView()`

Comment: And also to be clear enough, Log cat always returns the solution or the issue. You might need to check out the log cat first...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define your view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourview)

    ListView timesTableListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    SeekBar timesTablesSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**After your edit:**

Here, you are trying to initialize `ListView` & `SeekBar` before inflating the layout:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView timesTableListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SeekBar timesTablesSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Instead, ***inflate your layout first*** then initialize widgets or etc.

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Here, this is the solution.
            ListView timesTableListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
            SeekBar timesTablesSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

            // Here your other codes ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

**Tip to identify problem**

Always try to read logs specially error logs in case of App Crashing.
If you cannot find solution for that problem don't forget to post error logs while posting your question.

Happy coding :)